# phpmyadmin в openserver

Tags: phpmyadmin, openserver

!Здравствуйте, есть такая проблема, скачал openserver, первый раз запустил phpmyadmin, а войти не могу. Стандартные логин и пароль не проходят, я попробовал в phpmyadmin_config_inc.php изменить пароль и логин

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '1111';
```

Какого то черта добавился выбор сервера между localhost и 127.0.0.1, войти до сих пор никак. Если кто знает, что делать, помогите

Comment: Сколько раз использовал данное ПО, всегда был логин - `root`, а пароль пустой. Пробовали ли вы не вводить пароль?

Comment: Вот так сработало
Пользователь: mysql
Пароль: mysql

Comment: 127.0.0.1 это и есть localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Из руководства пользователя:
"Откройте [Меню → Дополнительно → PHPMyAdmin / MySQL менеджер]
Введите имя пользователя root без пароля
Нажмите кнопку [Вход]"

Вы точно тот phpmyadmin открываете? Не пытались случайно поднять апач и все остальное сами до openserver?

Кстати проверьте конфиг которвый правили. Сохранились ли ваши правки?

Answer (score 0):

Если в папке `[Диск:]\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin` при запуске/останове или перезапуске сервера отсутствует или удаляется файл `config.inc.php`, то сделайте следующее:

1. В папке `[Диск:]\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin` создать файл `phpmyadmin_config.inc.php` со следующим содержанием:

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['AllowRoot'] = true;
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['nopassword']  = true;
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['LoginCookieRecall'] = true;
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][1]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$2a$07$ct2druYbZdlTniMyaqwNhehPc9bFVfwBbfp57unK4SwXGHHVxABJy';
   $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'ru';
   $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 18000;
   ```
2. Перейти в папку `[Диск:]\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\libraries` и в файле `vendor_config.php` закомментировать строку

   ```
   define('CONFIG_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.inc.php');  --> //define('CONFIG_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.inc.php');
   ```

   и прямо под ней добавить:

   ```
   define('CONFIG_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'phpmyadmin_config.inc.php');
   ```
3. Перезапустите OpenServer. Все, Вы получили автовход в phpMyAdmin, кроме того исчезла ошибка о контрольной фразе 'Blowfish'.